# Problema con Swiper en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper

Estoy haciendo un carousel de tarjetas, la información la guardo dentro de un array de objetos y luego hago un map para mostrar una tarjeta por slide. Debo tener una centrada, y dos de cada lado. El problema es que cuando muevo el carousel hacia la derecha me queda una tarjeta centrada, tres a la izquierda y una sola a la derecha. y cuando muevo hacia la izquierda todo funciona perfecto. Intenté de todo pero no lo puedo solucionar.
Este es mi componente:

```
function CarouselCards() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Swiper
        effect={"coverflow"}
        grabCursor={true}
        centeredSlides={true}
        loop={true}
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 0,
          stretch: 0,
          depth: 150,
          modifier: 2.5,
          slideShadows: true,
        }}
        modules={[EffectCoverflow, Mousewheel, Keyboard, Autoplay]}
        autoplay={{ delay: 3000 }}
        mousewheel={true}
        keyboard={true}
        className="swiper_container"
      >
        {cardsData.map((card, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
            <Cards
              title={card.title}
              description={card.description}
              img={card.img}
            />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

y este mi css:

```
.container {
  max-width: 124rem;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.swiper_container {
  height: 55rem;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.swiper-slide {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 35rem;
  position: relative;
}
.swiper-slide div {
  filter: blur(1.2px);
}
.swiper-slide-active div {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .swiper_container {
    height: 47rem;
  }
  .swiper-slide {
    width: 24rem !important;
    height: 29rem !important;
  }
}
.swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  display: none;
}
```